# Can We Invite Anyone Else To The Private Beta?

Tags: support

I have some musical friends who might be interested in contributing to the private Beta?  Can I invite them or do they have to wait until the public Beta?

Comment: Perhaps being able to invite people in general and giving them badges/reputation might be a nice idea, it rewards people for growing the community. You could suggest this on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of any way, unless they committed to the proposal in Area 51.

Comment: Correct - only Area 51 committers may participate in the private beta.

Answer (score 3):

They will have to wait until the public beta. Which will be next week.